# Make room for siblings

Tags: jquery, autosize

I'm adapting a textarea autogrow plugin for my use case

http://jsfiddle.net/hY73a/

Changes are that it should be singleline from start and that it should leave room for siblings

I'm calculating the sibling width like this but I must be doing something wrong because as you can see both siblings does not fit

```
var siblings = $self.siblings();
var siblingsWidth = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < siblings.length; i++) 
    siblingsWidth += $(siblings[i]).outerWidth();
```

And then setting max-width like

```
$self.css({"max-width": $self.parent().innerWidth() - siblingsWidth });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this occurs is because the `span` elements are `display: inline` elements and the browser places spaces around them as it would for a text node. This causes the amount of space that is consumed by those components to be their width **plus** the amount of space between them.

In order to demonstrate this, I have removed all spacing between the `span` elements in the HTML.

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: solid black 1px">
    <textarea></textarea><span>SibOne</span><span>SibTwo</span>
</div>
```

Another area which needs attention is that the original code is not factoring in the amount of width used up by other components of the textarea's box model (e.g., margin, border, padding).

```
// Get the amount of horizontal space used up by the textarea margin, border, and padding
var selfUnfactoredWidth = parseInt($self.css('margin-left'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('margin-right'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('border-left-width'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('border-right-width'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('padding-left'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('padding-right'), 10);

$self.css({
    "max-width": $self.parent().innerWidth() - selfUnfactoredWidth - siblingsWidth
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KLK2q/3/)

Alternatively, you could use `box-sizing` to modify default [CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Box_model).

```
textarea { 
    resize: none;
    border: solid black 1px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Doing this will allow you to omit the border and padding width from before as the altered box model will take care of it.

```
// Get the amount of horizontal space used up by the textarea margin, border, and padding
var selfUnfactoredWidth = parseInt($self.css('margin-left'), 10) 
    + parseInt($self.css('margin-right'), 10);

$self.css({
    "max-width": $self.parent().innerWidth() - selfUnfactoredWidth - siblingsWidth
});
```

**[DEMO (Using `box-sizing`)](http://jsfiddle.net/KLK2q/4/)**